# If $|a_1|>1$, then the series $\sum\frac{a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n}{n}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_1,...,a_k$ be complex numbers different from $1$. I am trying to prove that if at least one of them has a module strictly greater than $1$, say $|a_1|>1$, then the series $\displaystyle\sum\frac{a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n}{n}$ diverges.

I have tried to prove that $\dfrac{a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n}{n}$ doesn't converge to $0$ as it should for the series to converge, and for that I've rewritten it as:

$$
\frac{|a_1^k+\cdots+a_n^k|}{k}=
\frac{|a_1|^k}{k}\Big|1+\Big(\frac{a_2}{a_1}\Big)^k
+\cdots+\Big(\frac{a_n}{a_1}\Big)^k\Big|
$$
I thus have to prove that the sum after the $1+\cdots,\,$ doesn't converge to $-1$, but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: Looking at my deleted answer, it is enough to prove the claim in the case where $|a_1|=\ldots = |a_n|$. But that looks quite hard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall show that, if at least one of $|a_1|,\ldots,|a_k|$ is larger than one, then the sequence $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{1}{n}(a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n)$ is not bounded, and hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}(a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n)$ diverges.

Assume, without loss of generality that
$$
|a_1|=\cdots=|a_m|=r>s=|a_{m+1}|\ge |a_{m+2}|\ge\cdots\ge|a_k|, 
$$
where $r>1$.

We shall use the following lemma (its proof is postponed).

**Lemma.** *If $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in \mathbb C$, with $|w_1|=\cdots=|w_m|=1$, then the sequence $z_n=w_1^n+\cdots+w_m^n$ does not tend to zero. Hence, there exists an $\eta>0$, such that $|z_n|\ge \eta$, for infinitely many $n$'s.*

So, setting $a_1=rw_1,\ldots,a_m=rw_m$, then the Lemma provides that there exists an $\eta>0$ and infinitely many $n$'s such that
$$
|a_1^n+\cdots+a_m^n|=r^n|w_1^n+\cdots+w_m^n|\ge \eta r^n,
$$
and hence $z_n$ is unbounded since, for infinitely many $n$'s
$$
|a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n|\ge |a_1^n+\cdots+a_m^n|-|a_{m+1}^n+\cdots+a_k^n|\ge r^n|w_1^n+\cdots+w_m^n|-(k-m)s^n \\\ge \eta r^n-(k-m)s^n=\eta r^n 
\left(1-\frac{k-m}{\eta}\Big(\frac{s}{r}\Big)^n\right)>\frac{\eta}{2}r^n,
$$
where the last inequality holds for sufficiently large $n$, as $s/r<1$.

*Proof of the Lemma.* Assume that $z_n\to 0$, as $n\to\infty$. The terms $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ do not have to be different. Say that there are only $\ell$ different complex numbers is the set $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}$, without loss of generality the $w_1,\ldots,w_\ell$, are different from each other and they appear $j_1,\ldots,j_\ell$ times, respectively (with $j_1+\cdots+j_\ell=k$). We have
$$
j_1w_1^n+\cdots+j_\ell w_\ell^n=z_n,\\
w_1 j_1w_1^n+\cdots+w_\ell j_\ell w_\ell^n=z_{n+1},\\ 
\cdots\\
w_1^{\ell-1} j_1w_1^n+\cdots+w_\ell^{\ell-1} j_\ell w_\ell^n=z_{n+\ell-1}.
$$ 
The above is viewed as an $\ell\times\ell$ linear system with *unknowns* the 
$j_1 w_1^n,\ldots,j_\ell w_\ell^n$ and system-matrix 
$A=(w_i^{j-1})_{i,j=1,\ldots,\ell}$ is the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), which is invertible, as the $w_1,\ldots,w_\ell$ are different from each other. Hence
$$
(j_1w_1^n,\ldots,j_\ell w_\ell^n)^T=A^{-1}(z_n,\ldots,z_{n+\ell-1})^T.
$$
So, if $z_n\to 0$, then so does the right-hand side of the above, and hence the left-hand side of the above. But $j_i|w_i|^n=j_i\ne 0$, for all $i=1,\ldots,\ell$. Contradiction. This concludes the proof of the Lemma.

Comment: The lemma is false as stated, as the moduli could be less than $1$ in which case you get convergence to $0.$

Comment: @zhw. You are right - I corrected formulation and the proof of the lemma.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that the series is convergent. Then the power series 
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_1^k+\cdots + a_n^k}k z^k
$$
is valid on $D=\{z: |z|<1\}$.

By differentiation, we have
$$
f'(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  (a_1^k + \cdots + a_n^k)z^{k-1}$$
is valid on $D$.

Moreover the series on the right side equals 
$$\frac{a_1}{1-a_1z} + \cdots +\frac{a_n}{1-a_n z}
$$
on $|z|<\min \{1/|a_i| : 1\leq i\leq n\}<1$ since each term is geometric series.

This function has a pole at $1/a_1$ which is inside $D$. This is a contradiction. Thus, the series must be divergent.

Comment: Isn't it rather $f'(z)=\sum_k^\infty k(a_1^k+...+a_n^k)z^{k-1}$? Also, I believe you have to prove each series converges before separating the sum (what if one pole and another `compensate'?).

Comment: $k$ doesn't appear in $f'(z)$ since $f(z)$ had $k$ in the denominator. Also, the series $f'(z)$ as the sum of rational functions is originally valid on $|z|<R$ where $R$ is minimum of $1/|a_i|$. But, is also valid on $D$ due to analytic continuation. And, the poles does not compensate.

Comment: The above comment is under the assumption of convergence of the series.

Comment: I don't master continuation so I can't really comment. My bad for the $k$.

Comment: This is a great solution! +1. However, you did not explain, in your answer, why you can pull apart the series as you did. It would be good to do that, since it's a big part of the proof. So, assuming $a_1$ has the largest modulus among the $a_m,$  each of the series $\sum a_m^kz^{k-1}$ is a geometric series converging in $\{|z|<1/|a_1|\}.$ In that smaller disc, we can pull apart the series as you did. We then see $\lim_{r\to 1^-}|f(r/|a_1|)| \infty,$ contradiction, since $f'$ was analytic in the unit disc. No need to speak of poles or analytic continuation.

Comment: @JohnDo Take a look at my comment. No need for analytic continuation ...

Comment: @zhw Great suggestion! I included the explanation of pulling apart the series.